# Select image from gallery - EACCESS Permission denied

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an image picker which will pick an image from the gallery and set it as the source of an `ImageView`. I'm using the code given below to do this but after I select an image in the gallery and the app returns to the `Fragment` I get the error :

```
I/PICTURE: Path: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160409_130537213.jpg
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160409_130537213.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
I/System.out: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160409_130537213.jpg
```

Here is the code:

Fragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    ........
    ........

    profile_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PICTURE);
            //SELECT_PICTURE = 1; defined in the fragment class
        }
    });

//The onActivityResult method
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String path = getPathFromCameraData(data, this.getActivity());
        Log.i("PICTURE", "Path: " + path);
        if (path != null) {
            profile_img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
        }
    }
}

//The string used to get the file(image) location
public static String getPathFromCameraData(Intent data, Context context) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return picturePath;
}
```

In the manifest, I've correctly stated that the app needs access to the device storage

```
<manifest>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application>
        ....
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it Beyond that, your code will not work for images on removable storage, and you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread. Please use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), passing it the `Uri` that you get in `onActivityResult()`. Your chosen library (e.g., Picasso) should handle [properly consuming the content from that `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do away with `getPathFromCameraData()` and change

```
profile_img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

to

```
profile_img.setImageURI(data.getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are picking image from gallery - you need this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```